# Django determine the value of a checkbox in a template from views

Tags: python, html, django, view

I have been trying to design a page in Django that works as follows.

My "list_books.html" page lists every book object handed to it.

I have a number of functions in views.py that determine what values would be used to determine the books shown on that page (i.e. all books by an author, all books in a series, all books with the same publication year)

ex.

```
@with_person_email
def book_list_author(request, person):
    return show_book_list(request, person.books, { 'author': person })

def show_book_list(request, blist, template_args, **kwargs):
    # this is just the defaults, will be replaced by data.update below
    data = { 'genre': None }

    try:
        # filters the list based on the keyword arguments
        blist = dataview.book_list(blist, **kwargs)
    except dataview.DataViewError as e:
        blist = None
        data['error'] = str(e)
    try:
        data['books'] = RequestPages(request, blist, desc=True)
    except Exception as e:
        if not utils.is_db_regex_exception(e):
            raise
        data['books'] = None
        data['error'] = 'Invalid regex.'

    data['genres'] = models.Genre.objects.order_by('kind', 'name')

    data.update(kwargs)
    data.update(template_args)
    return render(request, 'book_list.html', data)
```

book_list.html has a for loop that goes through each book and prints information about it. However, I have a boolean on the book model called "is_archived".

I want to be able to both set "is_archived" on the book from book_list.html, and filter the books shown between archived and not. I can do both of these things currently using a form that calls the following function handing it only archived books. However, this form has no idea what the previous criteria was to sort the books, so it shows all the archived books.

```
def commit_list_archived(request):
        return show_commit_list(request, models.Books.objects.filter(is_archived=True), { 'archived': True })
```

Settings the boolean is accomplished with a simple button that calls a view which changes the boolean field, and then returns to the previous page.

I want to be able to toggle between archived and non archived books. I tried using `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">` on the form to the archived posts to determine the previous criteria (author, year, genre, etc), however this doesn't seem to work.

I also considered using a checkbox that would toggle the books being shown, but I couldnt determine how to access the information of the checkbox form views.

For cleanliness sake I would like to remain on the books_list.html page, and just hand it either archived or none archived books. Again the problem is finding some way to call the right function both before and after view the archived books, to ensure I am still sorting by the same criteria.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your templates with how `commit_list_archived` is called?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard I figured it out. I just sent a query parameter ?archived=true and have the views check for this parameter and filter the commits they send to the html template accordingly